# Print rects onto an image on a JPanel

Tags: java, image, swing, printing, jpanel

I have a small image gallery that I can view using JButtons "next" and "previous". It works correctly.

What I want to do is to paint a rectangle (just the frame, without the filling) on the images displayed when clicking on them. If I click on the point (230,150) for example, I want my rect to appear in that point with its bottom left angle.

This is my code, I've tried many thing but nothing worked:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;
import java.awt.Image;

public class rectOnGallery extends JFrame{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private ImageIcon myImage1;
private ImageIcon myImage2;
private ImageIcon myImage3;
private ImageIcon myImage4;
JPanel ImageGallery = new JPanel();
private ImageIcon[] myImages = new ImageIcon[4];
private int curImageIndex=0;

int width;
int height;

public rectOnGallery(){

    double scale = 0.666667;
    width = (int) (scale * 612);
    height = (int) (scale * 792);

    myImage1 = new ImageIcon(((new ImageIcon("NewSign1.jpg")).getImage()).getScaledInstance(width, height, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH));
    myImage2 = new ImageIcon(((new ImageIcon("pdf2.jpg")).getImage()).getScaledInstance(width, height, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH));
    myImage3 = new ImageIcon(((new ImageIcon("pdfimg.jpg")).getImage()).getScaledInstance(width, height, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH));
    myImage4 = new ImageIcon(((new ImageIcon("images.jpg")).getImage()).getScaledInstance(width, height, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH));

    ImageGallery.add(new JLabel (myImage1));
    myImages[0]=myImage1;
    myImages[1]=myImage2;
    myImages[2]=myImage3;
    myImages[3]=myImage4;


     ImageGallery.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

         public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent evt) {
              if (myImages[curImageIndex] != null) {
                double x = (getWidth() - width) / 2;
                double y = (getHeight() - height) / 2;
                Rectangle2D.Double bounds = new Rectangle2D.Double(x, y, width, height);
                if (bounds.contains(evt.getPoint())) {
                  System.out.println("You clicked on " + evt.getX() + " x " + evt.getY());

                 **** HERE GOES SOMETHING THAT WRITES THE FRAME IN THE
                 **** POSITION (ent.getX() , evt.getY())

                }   
              }
         }
     });

     add(ImageGallery, BorderLayout.NORTH);

     JButton PREVIOUS = new JButton ("Previous");
     JButton NEXT = new JButton ("Next");

     JPanel buttons = new JPanel();
     buttons.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,4));
     buttons.add(PREVIOUS);
     buttons.add(NEXT);

     add(buttons, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

     //register listener
     PreviousButtonListener PreviousButton = new PreviousButtonListener ();
     NextButtonListener NextButton = new NextButtonListener ();

     //add listeners to corresponding componenets 
     PREVIOUS.addActionListener(PreviousButton);
     NEXT.addActionListener(NextButton);
}

private class PreviousButtonListener implements ActionListener {

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

        if(curImageIndex>0 && curImageIndex <= 3){              
            ImageGallery.remove(0);
            curImageIndex -- ;
            ImageIcon TheImage= myImages[curImageIndex];
            ImageGallery.add(new JLabel (TheImage));
            ImageGallery.validate();
            ImageGallery.repaint(); 
        }
        else{
            ImageGallery.remove(0);
            ImageGallery.add(new JLabel (myImage1));
            curImageIndex=0;
            ImageGallery.validate();
            ImageGallery.repaint();
        }
    }
}

private class NextButtonListener implements ActionListener {

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

        if(curImageIndex>=0 && curImageIndex < 3){
            ImageGallery.remove(0);
            curImageIndex ++ ;
            ImageIcon TheImage= myImages[curImageIndex];
            ImageGallery.add(new JLabel (TheImage));

            ImageGallery.validate();
            ImageGallery.repaint(); 
        }
        else{  
            ImageGallery.remove(0);
            ImageGallery.add(new JLabel (myImage4));
            curImageIndex=3;
            ImageGallery.validate();
            ImageGallery.repaint();
        }
    }
}

public static void main (String [] args){

    provaPosFirma frame = new provaPosFirma();

    frame.setSize(500, 600);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
}
}
```

As an alternative thing I've also tryed to paint the image of a rectangle on the other image but neighter this worked.

I know that I'm doing something wrong and that should be easier that appers but I'm not getting through this. If you can help me drawing the rect or another rectangular image on the displayed once it will be appreciated anyway.

thanks in advance

Comment: Follow standard Java naming conventions. Variable name should NOT start with an upper case character. Don't keep adding/removing components. Just use the setIcon(...) method to change the displayed image.

Comment: @camickr Thanks for the tips. I know about the setIcon() but it changes completely my image, doesn't prints another image on the previous

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do this, you'll want to create a custom subclass of JPanel, and use that instead of "ImageGallery." Then, in that class, override the paintComponent method to draw the rectangle you want. So the code would look like this.

```
class ImageGalleryPanel extends JPanel{
    private Point rectPosition = null;
    private Dimension rectSize; //Set the size of the rect

    public void setRectPosition(Point p){
        rectPosition = p;
    }

    private void drawRect(Graphics g){
        if(rectPosition != null){
            g.drawRect(rectPosition.x, rectPosition.y, rectSize.width, rectSize.height);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        drawRect(g);
    }
}
```

Replace your JPanel "ImageGallery" with this class, and assign the size of the rectangle you're going to draw. Where you have your comment to draw the rectangle, add these lines -

```
ImageGallery.setRectPosition(evt.getPoint());
ImageGallery.repaint();
```

I didn't test this code, so it might have some typos, but that's the basic idea you want when drawing to a JPanel. Override the paint method of the panel. Then, when you want to draw to it, change its properties to whatever they should be and call repaint(). If you just try to directly draw on it, then the repaint method will get called automatically, overwriting whatever changes you make.

Edit - In order to avoid the image being drawn over the rect, there's a few things you can do. You can change the paintComponent method to either "paint" or "paintChildren" and change the super.paintComponent function call to match. This would be quick and easy, but is considered bad practice. The other way which I think would work would be to, instead of overriding the JPanel's paintComponent, override the JLabel that you're adding to it. The code would be exactly the same, you would just apply it to the JLabel instead.

Comment: Ok, this worked fine generally, thanks, but it prints the rectangle under the image. I want it over. What could it be the reason? I dispaly the image before adding the rect...

Comment: You mean the Image is above the rect on the screen? If you change the "g.drawRect(...)" line to "g.drawRect(rectPosition.x, rectPosition.y - rectSize.height, rectSize.width, rectSize.height)" that should fix it. Or is it that the rect is drawn, and then the image is drawn, blocking some of the rect?

Comment: The second one. The rect is drawn on the frame, but under the image displayed (if I add it near the image a portion of the rect goes under)

Comment: Actually, I realized what the problem might be. The paintComponent method gets called before the paintChildren method, so the drawing of the image happens after the drawing of the rect. I'll update my post to say how to avoid this.

Comment: How can I exactly override the label I'm adding? Sorry I've tried but without any good result. Maybe I've misunderstood what you mean.

Comment: You would need to create a new subclass of JLabel which overrides paintComponent, and use that instead of the JLabel you're using. You could create a completely separate class for this, or use an inner classe; either way will work [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/innerclasses.html)